# Applying function on specific element of a list of list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list (3D data) and would like to apply the `RootMeanSquare` function on the fourth elements of each sublist. In fact, I am looking for `RootMeanSquar[{67,69,87,98,45,67,87,33,75}]`, `RootMeanSquar[{66,43,443,23,54}]` and `RootMeanSquar[{76,65,65,32,22,665,65,543,89,999}]`.

```
data3D={{{116.78, -290.14, -1757.55, 67}, {117.024, -290.15, -1757.86, 
   69}, {-83.7714, -286.992, -1901.55, 
   87}, {-82.8433, -281.52, -1900.81, 
   98}, {-97.3191, -273.23, -1892.02, 
   45}, {6.94247, -279.69, -1733.99, 
   67}, {120.195, -284.195, -1767.62, 
   87}, {-154.166, -283.542, -1851.78, 
   33}, {-149.813, -261.681, -1848.62, 
   75}}, {{-73.3052, -262.238, -1901.01, 
   66}, {-155.831, -261.886, -1834.57, 
   43}, {42.6028, -265.302, -1739., 
   443}, {-107.499, -270.669, -1886.43, 
   23}, {118.076, -270.128, -1778.35, 
   54}}, {{-138.659, -260.069, -1766.41, 
   76}, {-129.386, -285.284, -1741.13, 
   65}, {-128.958, -285.286, -1740.88, 
   65}, {98.259, -269.162, -1865.58, 
   32}, {108.071, -260.557, -1769.63, 22}, {110.842, -272.986, -1763.,
    665}, {-50.2524, -276.088, -1913.44, 
   65}, {-73.7019, -257.021, -1899.68, 
   543}, {-63.8887, -273.999, -1907.87, 
   89}, {-97.2162, -255.713, -1888.67, 999}}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rms = RootMeanSquare /@ (#[[All, -1]] & /@ data3D)

(* {2 Sqrt[3935/3], Sqrt[205899/5], Sqrt[352591/2]} *)
```

Check

```
rms === {RootMeanSquare[{67, 69, 87, 98, 45, 67, 87, 33, 75}], 
  RootMeanSquare[{66, 43, 443, 23, 54}], 
  RootMeanSquare[{76, 65, 65, 32, 22, 665, 65, 543, 89, 999}]}

(* True *)
```

Comment: Or just `RootMeanSquare /@ data3D[[All, All, -1]]`